# redirecting stdin to tempfile in script

Tags: linux, bash, pipe

I want to write a bash script that receives a list of files through a pipe, writes a tempfile and then starts a program (qiv - an image viewer) with this tempfile.

Example:

```
find . -atime 2 | piped_qiv
```

where piped_qiv would look something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
[receive file list through pipe] > /tmp/qiv_temp
qiv -fm -F /tmp/qiv_temp
rm /tmp/qiv_temp
```

I'm probably missing something very basic about bash scripting but I was not able to find a proper solution to this problem on this side or google.

Sidenote: I know I could also use `qiv $(find . …)` but using pipes would feel more natural to me.

Comment: use `find . -atime 2 | xargs piped_qiv`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use xargs:

```
find . -atime 2 -print0 | xargs -0 my_command
```

`-print0` will make `find` print each found file seperated by NUL (`\0`) and `-0` will make xargs read each line separated by the same.

Alternative if you want to pass a file you can use [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution):

```
% echo <(ls)
/dev/fd/63
```

And in your case:

```
qiv -fm -F <(my_command)
```

Or reading from stdin:

```
qiv -fm -F <(cat)
```

Comment: Process substitution only works if `qiv` doesn't try to seek backwards while reading the file.

Comment: @chepner Interesting didn't know that.

Comment: I think this could be the best solution, unless the number of files is very huge and all the files are needed at once.

Comment: Rather, to be more specific, the process substitution still works, but an attempt by `qiv` to seek backwards will fail.

Comment: `cat` already inherits its standard input from the script, so `cat <&0` is redundant; just use `qiv -fm -F <(cat)`.

Comment: Went with `qiv -fm -F <(cat)`, does what I want perfectly. qiv seems to "load" the whole file and save it internally, so searching backwards (by viewing the images from last in the list to first) did work wonderfully. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

You need a program that writes *its* standard input to standard output: `cat`.

```
#!/bin/bash
cat > /tmp/qiv_temp
qiv -fm -F /tmp/qiv_temp
rm /tmp/qiv_temp
```

Comment: And you also need to replace  /tmp/qiv_temp with something that is less likely to fail on multiple executions (e.g., use mktemp or similar) and use trap.

Comment: This answers my question fairly well (and the mktemp point is also duly noted). I went with the other answer though because `qiv -fm -F <(cat)` really is nicer and can be used as a bash alias too.

Comment: Either one can be defined as a function, which is preferable to using an alias in almost every case: `piped_qiv () { f=$(mktemp); cat > "$f"; qiv -fm -F "$f"; rm "$f"; }`.